# Bring interface down by MAC or Bus address not name

Tags: linux, network-adapter

Is there a way to bring network interface down by MAC or better yet by bus address from lspci

what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
ifconfig [BUS ADDRESS from lspci] down
```

this of course does not work, with ifconfig nor with ip link set dev down

thanks in advance

Comment: Curious what is the use case for this.

Comment: we are checking with lspci network card speed and then store those bus addresses and then by the bus addresses binding network cards, what we do is changing kernel driver for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure – first find out which interface names belong to the device. They can be listed through the sysfs, in the `net/` subdirectory of your PCI device:

```
$ echo /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/net/*
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.5/net/eth0
```

You can use that in your `ifconfig-by-pciid` wrapper script. (Example provided below.)

(Note that it's possible for one PCI device to host several network interfaces, especially for Wi-Fi.)

---

Attachment: `pcip.pl`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# pcip - 'ip' wrapper translating PCI & MAC addresses to interface names
# (c) 2015 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
# Released under the MIT License <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT>
#
# Match by PCI device:
#
#     pcip link set pci:03:00.0 up
#
# Match by MAC address:
#
#     pcip addr add 10.0.42.1/16 dev mac:48:5d:04:85:fc:d7
#
# Use with other commands besides `ip`:
#
#     pcip -c ifconfig mac:485d.0485.fcd7 up

use v5.10;
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case bundling);
use List::Util qw(max);

sub _warn { warn "$0: $_[0]\n"; return; }

sub read_line {
    my ($path) = @_;

    if (open(my $fh, "<", $path)) {
        chomp(my $line = <$fh>);
        close($fh);
        return $line;
    } else {
        _warn("could not open '$path': $!");
    }
}

sub canonicalize_mac {
    my ($addr) = @_;

    my $vbyte = qr/[0-9a-f]{1,2}/;
    my $fbyte = qr/[0-9a-f]{2}/;
    my @match;

    # convert Windows-style addresses with dashes
    $addr = lc($addr);
    $addr =~ y/-/:/;
    # expand missing leading 0's, parse Cisco-style addresses
    if (@match = $addr =~ /^($vbyte):($vbyte):($vbyte):($vbyte):($vbyte):($vbyte)$/ or
        @match = $addr =~ /^($fbyte)($fbyte)\.($fbyte)($fbyte)\.($fbyte)($fbyte)$/ or
        @match = $addr =~ /^($fbyte)($fbyte)($fbyte)($fbyte)($fbyte)($fbyte)$/)
    {
        return join(":", map {sprintf("%02x", hex $_)} @match);
    }
    return $addr;
}

sub ifname_from_pci {
    my ($pciid) = @_;

    unless ($pciid =~ /^[0-9a-f]{4}:/) {
        $pciid = "0000:$pciid";
    }
    return map {basename($_)}
           glob("/sys/bus/pci/devices/$pciid/net/*/");
}

sub ifname_from_mac {
    my ($arg) = @_;

    my $addr = canonicalize_mac($arg);
    if (!$addr) {
        _warn("invalid MAC address '$arg'");
    } else {
        return map {basename($_)}
               grep {read_line("$_/address") eq $addr}
               grep {-f "$_/address"}
               glob("/sys/class/net/*/");
    }
}

sub expand {
    my ($arg) = @_;

    for ($arg) {
        if (/^pci:(.+)/) {
            return ifname_from_pci($1);
        }
        elsif (/^mac:(.+)/) {
            return ifname_from_mac($1);
        }
        else {
            _warn("unknown expansion '$arg'");
        }
    }
}

sub replace_first {
    my ($func, $start, @args) = @_;

    my $pos = -1;
    my $arg = undef;
    for my $i ($start..$#args) {
        if ($args[$i] =~ /^(pci|mac):/) {
            $pos = $i;
            $arg = $args[$i];
            last;
        }
    }
    if ($pos == -1) {
        return $func->(@args);
    } else {
        my @names = expand($arg);
        if (!@names) {
            _warn("could not translate '$arg' to an interface name");
        } else {
            return map {
                $args[$pos] = $_;
                replace_first($func, $pos+1, @args)
            } @names;
        }
    }
}


my $cmd = "ip";
my $fail = 0;

my $handler = sub {
    my (@args) = @_;

    my $ret = (system {$args[0]} @args) >> 8;
    if ($ret) {
        _warn("call {@args} failed with code $ret");
    }
    if ($fail) {
        exit $ret;
    }
    return $ret;
};

GetOptions(
    "c|command=s" => \$cmd,
    "f|fail!" => \$fail,
);

my @cmd = ($cmd, @ARGV);
my @ret = replace_first($handler, 0, @cmd);

if (@ret) {
    exit max(@ret);
} else {
    _warn("no commands were run");
    exit 1;
}
# vim: ts=4:sw=4:et
```